# How to change side by side divs to stack on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to get my 2 divs (which are side by side) to change to stacked divs when viewed on mobile as shown in the fiddle, but I would like "two to be on top and "one" to be second.

Here is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/d3d4hb3t/

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 69%;
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .one {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .two {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
```

I know the simple solution would be to swap divs one and two around, but since the code I have is complicated, I was hoping there was an easier solution using just CSS.

Comment: Swap the order of the divs in your HTML and it will work without changing any of your CSS - Demo... http://jsfiddle.net/d3d4hb3t/1/

Comment: just swap, it will be easier than anything else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

Added a flexbox approach below:

<kbd>**[UPATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mrbwgyjv/)**</kbd>

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.one {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.two {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .one,
  .two {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
</div>
```

**Original answer**

If you're stuck with the markup, you can still use the magic css table layout to change the order of the 2 divs. I updated it all, just to keep the consistency.

How those `display` values work, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> `display: table;` - behaves like `<table>` element.
>
> `display: table-cell;` - behaves like `<td>` element.
>
> `display: table-header-group;` - behaves like `<thead>` element.
>
> `display: table-footer-group;` - behaves like `<tfoot>` element.

<kbd>**[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59mo0s9g/)**</kbd>

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.one,
.two {
  display: table-cell;
}

.one {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.two {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .one {
    display: table-footer-group;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .two {
    display: table-header-group;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you don't want swap them.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c8x49afg/
Just use position relative for divs pulling the second up and pushing the first down.

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 69%;
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .one {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .two {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    one
  </div>


  <div class="two">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have needed to do this exact thing when working in an enterprise CMS where the source order could not be changed on mobile.

The solution I have used is to set a general container for the two Divs and make that display as a table. You can then set the Div you want to show first as `display:table-group-header` and set the one to show after it as `display:table-group-footer`

If you want to keep the colored borders, you may have to introduce an inner div for each that holds your content.

I have created a Fiddle that shows it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/0brc4xc7/